# Unable to add SSH key in GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github, ssh-keys

In our GitHub we have around 20 repositories. For the CI Build we have enabled Git polling option.

Our Jenkins master has attached with multiple nodes. For Git Polling we usually add our Jenkins Master ssh key to repective user's GitHub under settings SSH key section. While adding the key getting Error: Key already in use. Let me know to add the same.

As per error message for other repository build we have already added our Jenkins Master key with different user's
 account.

Comment: Did you try generate a new one?

Comment: No I did not tried on Jenkins Master server. So I need to generate new key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SSH key can only be attached to a single user on GitHub, since it is used to authenticate and authorize this user. There is no way to add to multiple accounts.

GitHub provides a guide about dealing with SSH keys for automated scripts here: [Managing deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/). The two interesting options are:

Typically, you would use [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) to gain access to a repository from a server. Deploy keys have a similar restriction as a user's SSH key though, and can only be attached to a single repository. This reduces the potential damage that can be done if the key is compromised. For build servers they are often not well suited, because it is often not possible to configure authentication per repository.

For your use case, a [machine user](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users) seems to be the best option. This is a dedicated user account that is only used by your build server. Make sure to use a strong password and two factor authentication for this account, and add Jenkins' master key to it. You can then add the machine user as a collaborator on the repositories you need in Jenkins.

With regards to security, be as restrictive as possible: only the repositories that are required, and only with read permissions. This is also the reason why you should use a machine user instead of an actual user account. For Jenkins, you (usually) don't need write access to a repository. By limiting the access rights for the server key, the impact of a compromised key is reduced.

Comment: Ok Mr.Jdno perfect suggestion. I will try the same on monday and then update you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jdno, Thank you for the quick support. Deploy key on particular repoistory method also resulted same error(Key is in use) However machine user method working perfectly. Thank you.